# How to pointing skrollr-menu from other site?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have 2 sites: a main-site and a blog site. Both of them have same navigation.

Main-site is a parallax site using skrollr and skrollr-menu. For the blog, I used Wordpress.

The code in main-site for the navigation and related `div`:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#about" data-menu-top="2114">About Us</a>
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="#lin" data-menu-top="2334">Lin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#young" data-menu-top="5080">Young</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


<div class="clearfix" id="about scroll-3">
    <div class="about-us">
        <h2 data-500-top="opacity:1;" data-anchor-target="#scroll-3 .about-us h2" data-top="opacity: 1">About Us</h2>

        <div class="col-3" data-436-top="opacity:0;top:-100px" data-top="opacity: 1;top:0px" data-anchor-target="#scroll-3 .col-3">
            <a href="#lin" data-menu-top="2334">LIN</a>
            <hr>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3" data-436-top="opacity:0;top:-100px" data-top="opacity: 1;top:0px" data-anchor-target="#scroll-3 .col-3">
            <a href="#young" data-menu-top="5080">YOUNG</a>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the link from blog to back to main-site:

```
<a href="#about" data-menu-top="2114">About</a>
```

Comment: This looks right. It is working on the demo page, click here http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr-menu/#section1 which jumps down 1000px. If it's not working for you, maybe you can share a link to the website.

Comment: It works in Firefox but not Chrome. Here's an open issue for that https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-menu/issues/32

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it works on Firefox, Alex! I don't realize it. Still looking for the solution to make it work on Chrome

Comment: I just don't have the time atm to fix all of these bugs...

Comment: No problem, Alex. Thank you for responding my message.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on code used for prallax, but in most cases [(like here)](http://melonweb.pl#service) you can use http://sampleURL.com#about

Comment: Yep, just curious why it's not working at the site. Thanks for your answer, @Michal. I'm still analyze it.

Comment: not workin because you have to pass "data-menu-top" value. You need to add on second site (with parallax) some script to use #about anchor to set it.

Comment: so I need to put "data-menu-top" value in both of site?

Comment: on one you want to be scrolled (I wouldn't call it parallax) or (if using script linked by Prinzhorn) instead of pixel values use id="about" on element you want scroll to